# Spring boot : REST API behaviour inconsistent post version upgrade

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I have issue after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE from 1.5.10.RELEASE. Our controller API looks like -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/card", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public CardRespDTO getCards(@RequestParam String profileId, @RequestParam(required = false) String banner, @RequestParam(required = false) String paymentGatewayVersion);
```

Consumer were able to call this API by not passing profileId param but by just providing some USER_ID header. But post the version upgrade, those calls are failing with below error -

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'profileId' is not present
```

Can someone please help identifying the issue here? We can't ask consumer to make a change.

Comment: I guess you need to set required=false for profileId as well, @RequestParam(required = false) String profileId.

Comment: Thank you @OnkarMusale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking `profileId` as not required should do the trick:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/card", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public CardRespDTO getCards(@RequestParam(required = false) String profileId, 
    @RequestParam(required = false) String banner, 
    @RequestParam(required = false) String paymentGatewayVersion)
```